# Java Swing GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layoutmanager

Создаю класс, **ImageGroup**, который будет выводить группу фотографий на экран.
Размеры фотографий могут отличаться друг от друга. ImageGroup наследует класс JPanel и устанавливает менеджер расположения GridBagLayout.
Моя проблема заключается в том, что менеджер расположения игнорирует размеры блоков и ячейки становятся узкими по высоте.
Ниже я представил рисунок, как должны выглядеть ячейки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**class ImageGroup**

```
    public class ImageGroup extends JPanel{

        private List<ImagePanel> imageList;
       // private GridBagConstraints constraints;

        public ImageGroup(List<ImagePanel> imageList) {

            this.imageList = imageList;
            this.setSize(new Dimension(240, 200));
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        }

        public void arrangeElements() {
            int previosPhotoSpacing = 0;
            int panelSize = 240;
            int x = 0, y = 0;

            GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

            constraints.anchor =  GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            constraints.weightx = 1.0;
            constraints.weighty = 1.0;
            constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

            for(ImagePanel entry : imageList) {
                Dimension d = entry.getSize();
                int photoSize = (int) d.getWidth();


                if(previosPhotoSpacing <= 0) {
                    previosPhotoSpacing = panelSize - photoSize;

                    constraints.gridy =  y++;
                    constraints.gridx = x;
                    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; 


                } else {
                    constraints.gridx = x++;
                    constraints.gridy = y;
                    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
                }

                this.add(entry, constraints);

            }

//Чтобы заполнить всё оставшиеся пространство 
            constraints.gridy = 9999;
            constraints.weighty = 9999f;
            constraints.ipadx = 0;
            constraints.ipady = 0;
            constraints.insets = new Insets( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
            constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            this.add( Box.createVerticalStrut( 0 ), constraints );
        }



}
```

**Добавление фотографий:**

```
File[] files = fileopen.getSelectedFiles();
                List<ImagePanel> ipList = new ArrayList<>();

                ImagePanel ip1 = new ImagePanel();
                ip1.setBackground(ImageIO.read(files[0]));
                ip1.setSize(new Dimension(224, 160));
                ip1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(224, 160));

                ImagePanel ip2 = new ImagePanel();
                ip2.setBackground(ImageIO.read(files[1]));
                ip2.setSize(new Dimension(110, 80));
                ip2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(110, 80));

                ImagePanel ip3 = new ImagePanel();
                ip3.setBackground(ImageIO.read(files[2]));
                ip3.setSize(new Dimension(110, 80));
                ip3.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(110, 80));

                ipList.add(ip1);
                ipList.add(ip2);
                ipList.add(ip3);

                GroupImage gi = new GroupImage(ipList);
                gi.arrangeElements();

                jPanel11.add(gi);
```

**Класс ImagePanel**

```
    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private BufferedImage scaled;

        public ImagePanel() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        public void setBackground(BufferedImage value) {
            if (value != img) {
                this.img = value;


                repaint();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            if (getWidth() > img.getWidth() || getHeight() > img.getHeight()) {
                scaled = getScaledInstanceToFill(img, getSize());
            } else {
                scaled = img;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);           
            if (scaled != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - scaled.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - scaled.getHeight()) / 2;

                g.drawImage(scaled, x, y, this);
            }
        }


        public static BufferedImage getScaledInstanceToFill(BufferedImage img, Dimension size) {

            double scaleFactor = getScaleFactorToFill(img, size);

            return getScaledInstance(img, scaleFactor);

        }
}
```

Comment: Сделал так: 
`constraints.ipadx = (int) d.getWidth();
constraints.ipady = (int) d.getHeight();`
В итоге получилось то, что надо. Правильное ли решение?